# How to add a current location marker on Google Map

Tags: javascript, wordpress, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have recently developed a website but I haven't been able to show the current location marker on the Google map after the location was found.

You can have a look on https://www.storra.com/listings/

I have added a custom listener to the function.php based on Listify auto-locate function but didn't manage to add the marker to the map. The code is as following,

```html
function listify_custom_autolocation() {
 if ( ! ( is_front_page() || listify_is_job_manager_archive() ) ) {
  return;
 }
?>
 <script>
  var triggered = false;
  jQuery(document).on( 'facetwp-loaded', function() {
   if ( ! triggered ) {
    var locate = jQuery( '.locate-me' );
    locate.trigger( 'click' );
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                    parseFloat(coords[0]),
                    parseFloat(coords[1])
                ),
                info: new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                    content: val.title + val.distance
                })
          });
   }
   triggered = true;
  });
 </script>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'listify_custom_autolocation', 9999 );
```

Would very much appreciate if someone could guide me out.
Thank you!

Comment: What exactly is not working. Any error message apart from "jQuery is not defined"? You don´t show as the relevant code. Is your map instance reachable from outside? What is the output of `coords[0]`?

Comment: @elsololobo the relevant code was pasted down there. thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 3):

You could use this one for your locate function:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var pos = {
            lat: position.coords.latitude,
            lng: position.coords.longitude
        };
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: pos,
            map: map,
            title: 'Your position'
        });
        map.setCenter(pos);
    }, function() {
        //handle location error (i.e. if user disallowed location access manually)
    });
} else {
  // Browser doesn't support Geolocation
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following is the relevant code on the backend. I tried adding the code given by @mxlse but didn't seem to work too.

```html
  AutoLocateView.prototype.find = function() {
        var cv, error, filters, success;
        cv = this.collectionView;
        filters = this.filters;
        if (!navigator.geolocation) {
          return;
        }
        success = function(position) {
          var lat, lng;
          lat = position.coords.latitude;
          lng = position.coords.longitude;
          cv.set({
            'lat': lat,
            'lng': lng
          });
          return $('.locate-me').removeClass('loading');
        };
        error = function() {
          $('.locate-me').removeClass('loading');
          return filters.startup();
        };
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
        return this;
      };
```